# automaticly genereated Set of values in a Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How do i make a array which contain the data values of a varible which is constantly random over the time.

Im getting distance value as varible '**rssi**' over time. I would like to save each postion along with the others in a array '**arr**'

This should be done in javascript.

```js
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var server = require('http').createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);
    var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
    var rssi = {};

    server.listen(port,function(){
     console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
    });

    // Routing
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    // Server Configuration
    var scanner = io.of('/scanner');

    scanner.on('connection',function(socket){
     
      console.log('Scanner is connected');
     
      socket.on('deviceData1',function(msg) {

      
      
       
       var rssi = msg.rssi;
       
       var arr = [];
       arr.push(rssi);
       console.log(arr);
      
       
       
      });


    });
```

the result i get is just a one value of rssi in a array.

```
example = [89] .
        = [20]
but i need some thing like arr = [89 ,20 ,56]
```

Comment: can you give an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: As @gurvinder372 said, we'll also need to see some code to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `arr` outside the `on` method

```
  var arr = [];
  scanner.on('connection',function(socket){
        console.log('Scanner is connected');
        socket.on('deviceData1',function(msg) {
            var rssi = msg.rssi;
            arr.push(rssi);
            console.log(arr);
        });
```

Now `arr` will show all the values which have been added to it as and when `on` method is called.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, it's a simple `Array.push()`.

```
var dAx = [];
dAx.push(DA);
```

Comment: but it produced on a array with one data. but i receive many data as DA.